# extracting a substring in a string with some conditions

Tags: string, ocaml

I hope you are well !
I present my problem to you. I have a string (on a single line) and the idea is to iterate the string from a given position in the string, go left character by character and stop when we meet a separator (the separators are in the list), and do the same on the right and at the end, put the two together to form the word you are looking for. I wrote the following function, but it doesn't quite work, when I position myself at the end of a word like in position 4, it returns me a string "" instead of returning "this". When I go to position 1, it sends me "his" and not "this". When I put myself in position 44, I output "tha" instead of "that". On the other hand, in the middle of the string as for position 36 or 40, it works.
Can anyone help me fix these bugs?

```
(* separators *)
let sep_list = [';';',';'(';')';'.';' ';]

(* my string to test *)
let my_str = "this is my string for testing purpose, only that"

(* my function *)
let search_word_in_cursor (str:string) (char_list:char list) (pos:int) : string = 
  let rec foo_left (str:string) (char_list:char list) (pos:int) (ret:string) : string =
    if ((List.exists (fun x -> Char.equal x str.[pos]) char_list) || (pos <= 0)) then ret 
    else if (pos == 0) then String.make 1 str.[pos] ^ ret 
    else foo_left str char_list (pos - 1) ((String.make 1 str.[pos]) ^ ret)
  in
  let rec foo_right (str:string) (char_list:char list) (pos:int) (ret:string) : string =
    if ((List.exists (fun x -> Char.equal x str.[pos]) char_list) || (pos >= (String.length str - 1))) then ret 
    else foo_right str char_list (pos + 1) (ret ^ (String.make 1 str.[pos]))
  in
  let sl = foo_left str char_list pos "" in 
  let sr = foo_right str char_list pos "" in 
  if (sr == "" && sl == "") then "" 
  else if (sr == "" && sl != "") then sl
  else if (sr != "" && sl == "") then sr
  else (String.sub sl 0 (String.length sl - 1)) ^ sr

  (* expects and results *)
  let () = 
      print_string (search_word_in_cursor my_str sep_list 4); (* expected:"this" output:"" *)
      print_string (search_word_in_cursor my_str sep_list 1);(* expected:"this" output:"his" *)
      print_string (search_word_in_cursor my_str sep_list 44);(* expected:"that" output:"tha" *)
      print_string (search_word_in_cursor my_str sep_list 36);(* expected:"purpose" output:"purpose" *)
      print_string (search_word_in_cursor my_str sep_list 40)(* expected:"only" output:"only" *)
```

Thank you, goog to y'all !

Comment: So starting from a position in the string : go to left until you meet a separator if you don't meet any go to the right ?

Comment: String positions are numbered starting at 0. So position 4 is the first space of the string. What is the result supposed to be if you start on a separator? An empty string seems like one reasonable result.

Comment: @Butanium no, go to left, if we got a separator, we stop, if we don't got one, we continue to the begenning and return that. After, we do the same with to the right, and return that too.
At the end, we assemble the left and the right one and return the "word". it is the result at the end.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield normally, we should return **ret** in my function, which will be an empty string, and go to the other side. The goal is to find the word delimited by two separators from the cursor function, there it's just my algorithm and what I thought to do

Comment: I think I understand the general purpose of the function, but I wonder what the answer is supposed to be if your starting position is located at a separator. In that case it seems like there's no word to return. So, the result "" (empty string)  for the first test case seems correct. I don't see why "this" is expected. What if the starting position is in the middle of a series of 100  spaces? Are you supposed to return the word after the spaces? Before the spaces?